# Finding vertex of a parabola -conflicting answers

Tags: conic-sections, wolfram-alpha

For a given problem $g(x) = 5x^2 - 2x +1$, we were expected to describe the graph. WolframAlpha and I are finding conflicting issues. I do not think I made an approximation anywhere that would explain the difference.

For a given problem $g(x) = 5x^2 -2x +1$, the problem is already in the form of $y = ax^2 +bx + c$
If we can identify the vertex coordinates $(h, k)$ using $h = -b/2a$ and $k = f (-b/2a)$
If $h = -b/2a$ for given problem is $-(-2)/2(5) = 4/10 = 2/5 = h$
If $k = f (-b/2a)$ (or in our case, $g(-b/2a) = g (2/5) = 5(2/5)^2 - 2(2/5) +1 = 5 (4/25) - (4/5) +1 = 20/25 - 4/5 + 1 = 4/5 - 4/5 +1 = 1$
Then vertex coordinates $(h, k) = (2/5, 1)$

But if I enter g(x) = 5x^2 -2x +1 in WolframAlpha, it says (h, k) is (1/5, 4/5). What am I missing in my work that is leading to this problem over and over again? There is a simple error I cannot find which is very embarrassing.

Comment: You've multiplied $2 \cdot 2$ rather than dividing.

Comment: Wow. You're right. That fixes everything. This is so embarrassing to not have been able to have found it on my own - I've taken math up to linear algebra and have had to do a lot of review problems for a class I'm taking in another department and didn't realize how decayed i'd become.

Comment: @T.Bongers Is there a way I can +1 or upvote your comment on here?

Comment: Why on earth would anyone downvote this question? It is perfectly suited for this forum--the OP describes in detail what he has tried, and is asking for a more experienced eye to spot his error. Good grief!

Comment: Well to be fair @MPW, it was a very basic arithmetic error.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error,  $$h=\frac{-b}{2a}=\frac{-(-2)}{2*5}=\frac{2}{10}=\frac{1}{5}$$

You make:

$$h=\frac{-2b}{2a}=\frac{-(-2*2)}{10}=\frac{4}{10}=\frac{2}{5}$$

So, the true value of $h$ is $h=\frac{1}{5}$ and $f(h)=\frac{4}{5}$ that is the answer Wolfram Alpha give you.